# heroku-connectと同期したpostgresにinsertできない。

Tags: php, heroku, laravel

laravel5でheroku-connectを利用するにあたって、
同期したPostgresにlaravel5で入力したデータをpostgresにinsertすることができません。

データの取得は問題なくできますがinsert時に失敗してしまいます。

お手数ですが解決方法をご存知の方、よろしくお願いします。

エラーメッセージはこちらです。

> QueryException in Connection.php line 651: SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined
>   function: 7 ERROR: function get_xmlbinary() does not exist LINE 1:
>   SELECT (get_xmlbinary() = 'base64') ^ HINT: No function matches the
>   given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type
>   casts. QUERY: SELECT (get_xmlbinary() = 'base64') CONTEXT: PL/pgSQL
>   function hc_TABLENAME_status() line 3 at IF (SQL: insert into
>   TABLENAME ("NAME") values (VALUE) returning "id")

> PDOException in Connection.php line 321: SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined
>   function: 7 ERROR: function get_xmlbinary() does not exist LINE 1:
>   SELECT (get_xmlbinary() = 'base64') ^ HINT: No function matches the
>   given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type
>   casts. QUERY: SELECT (get_xmlbinary() = 'base64') CONTEXT: PL/pgSQL
>   function hc_TABLENAME_status() line 3 at IF

Comment: `You might need to add explicit type casts` との文言がありますので、明示的に cast してあげれば良いのではないでしょうか。`get_xmlbinary()::text = 'base64'::text` ただ、SELECT 文に `^ HINT` とあるので、この部分で同様のエラーが発生するかもしれません。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
明示的にcastしたんですが、変わらずなんですよね。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$schema = array('salesforce', 'public');
```

スキーマに'public'を追加することで解決しました。
もともと指定されていて、取り除く必要がなかったようです。